# Mongoose Discriminator : NodeJS/Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discriminator

I have developed CRUD APIs using Express and in one of the Create APIs, I wish to extend my Mongoose Model Schema on the basis of a boolean flag supplied in a request body.

Create API Body **(required to be stored in the Database in this format):**

```
{
  "name" : "John Doe",
  "admin" : true,
  "adminControl1" : "Some Control",
  "adminControl2" : "Some Other Control",
}
```

but the Data stored in my MongoDB is as follows:

```
{
  "name" : "John Doe",
  "admin" : "true",
}
```

My Model file is as follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var options = { discriminatorKey: 'admin' }

var userSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
  }
}, options);

const Event = mongoose.model('Event',userSchema);

const addedSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  adminControl1 : {
    type: String
  },
  adminControl2 : {
    type: String
  },
},options);

const addedSchemaEvent = Event.discriminator(true,addedSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', userSchema,'users');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Event.discriminator("Event2", addedSchema);
```

The first param of discriminator is the new model name

This is an example of my models

```
let Area: any = mongoose.model("Area", areaSchema);
let Country: any = Area.discriminator("Country", countrySchema);
let City: any = Area.discriminator("City", citySchema);

module.exports = {
   Area: Area,
   Country: Country,
   City: City,
};
```

Where areaSchema is the basic schema and countrySchema and citySchema are the added schema

And I import the models like this

```
const Area_ = require("../models/Area");
const Area = Area_.Area;
const City = Area_.City;
const Country = Area_.Country;
```

Comment: Can you share the entire model.js structure?
Should i export the Event as well?

Comment: still not getting through. any JSfiddle?